# What is the recommended way to reduce the number of HTTP requests for images on RIA using Ext.js4?

Tags: css, image, extjs, ria, css-sprites

What is the recommended way to reduce the number of HTTP requests for images on RIA using Ext.js 4?

As per [YSlow performance rules](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#num_http), the preferred method is to use '[CSS Sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)', which can be very costly to implement and to maintain, even if using SpriteMe. Maybe there is already a solution for Ext.Js. I'm using version 4.1.3.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @AlienArrays. If you're dealing with legacy RIA with up to 5000 images (PNG and GIF) you would want some kind of automation, right? I hope there is already something aimed at ext.js 4 framework, so I can reuse for ext.js images and easily add mine too.